# Is there a way to work around the "no <listen> line. Nothing to do !" HAProxy error?

Tags: haproxy, service-discovery

When we start HAProxy, it immediately quits with the `no <listen> line. Nothing to do !` error. We want it to start up normally and reload it later with the right configuration once our service discovery application is ready. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a listener for the statistics page?

```
listen stats :1936
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /
    stats auth Username:Password
```